# Nouveau driver: colours and shading all wrong

Tags: nvidia, colors, nouveau, gpu-driver

How can I deal with the colour problems that the latest Nouveau driver provides? As you can see from the attachment, this causes transparency where it shouldn't, red where it should be grey and in other dialogues, it actually hides text (which I guess is a manifestation of the text being transparent).

I've tried downgrading `libdrm-nouveau2` to version 2.4.67-1 (which according to apt-cache showpkg libdrm-nouveau2 is the only over version available to me) but that didn't do anything.

I have an nVidia GeForce GTX 750 running Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I have tried the proprietary drivers, but they cause freezing, probably in connection with the containers I'm running.

This is what I have for Nouveau:

```
$ dpkg -l *nouveau*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                          Version                             Architecture                        Description
+++-=============================================================-===================================-===================================-================================================================================================================================
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:amd64                                         2.4.91-2~16.04.1                    amd64                               Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                                    1:1.0.12-1build2                    amd64                               X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
```

Edit: meh! I just went w/the onboard Intel graphics driver. Works fine now.

[image: gnome-calculator with messed up colours]